# Why I can't able to slice the first 5 values from this object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show the list of food types whereas I need to display the first 5 values in the html. While using slice I am getting this error Property 'slice' does not exist on type '{ categories: Category[]; }

```
   loadcategoriesfood(): Observable<{ categories: Category[] }> {
    return this.http.get<{ categories: Category[] }>(
      this.recipies.listofcategories + 'categories.php',
      {}
    ).pipe(map((food) => food.slice(0, 5)));
  }
```

Comment: I think you're trying to slice an object. You need to write food.categories to access the array.

Comment: I can't able to access the value by trying food.categories in map

Comment: @harshal Can you pleasewrite it and add it as a solution on how to write food.categories ?

Comment: `.pipe(map((food) => food.slice(0, 5)));` can you flip this too `.pipe(tap(result => console.log(result)), map((food) => food.slice(0, 5)));` and let us know what it console logs?

Comment: @Mathew Berg still seeing the error Property 'slice' does not exist on type '{ categories: Category[]; }' after using your updated code but in the result console I'm getting the object = {categories: Array(14)}.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the return type of the GET method, I'm assuming your observable will return `{ categories: Category[] }`. This means you'll receive an object (`food`) inside your map operator's callback. hence you'll need to apply the slice method on the property of the food object which is `categories`.

If this doesn't work try adding a console.log or breakpoint inside the map operator to determine what value you're receiving and if that value is an array.

Comment: Can you share the result if you can ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your console log showing that "food" has a sub property of categories you need to slice on that if you want to slice on anything.

```typescript
 loadcategoriesfood(): Observable<{ categories: Category[] }> {
    return this.http.get<{ categories: Category[] }>(
      this.recipies.listofcategories + 'categories.php',
      {}
    ).pipe(map((food) => food.categories.slice(0, 5))); // food.categories.slice
  }
```

Comment: Type 'Observable<Category[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{ categories: Category[]; }>'.
  Property 'categories' is missing in type 'Category[]' but required in type '{ categories: Category[]; }'.            /// getting this error after replacing your code @mathewberg